# Context MkIV straight single quote in code listing

Tags: context, punctuation

I'm trying out Context (MkIV, luatex) and in the following snippet, while the double quotes are straight, the single quotes get turned into "forward" ones.

This only happens when I select a new monospace font, e.g. Consolas. (The quotes I get are not the Consolas straight ones.)

How can I turn this off?

```
\setuppapersize[A4][A4]

% Without the switch to consolas, the quotes are fine.
\definefontfamily[f][serif][Garamond]
\definefontfamily[f][sans][Gill Sans MT][rscale=0.9]
\definefontfamily[f][mono][Consolas][rscale=0.8] 
% tried: tlig-no,trep=no but didn't help
\setupbodyfont[f]
\setupbodyfont[12pt]

\starttext

\starttyping
-- in lua you can use both single and double quotes
a = 'single quoted'
b = "double quoted"
\stoptyping

\stoptext
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set `features=none`.  (I used Latin Modern Mono because I don't have Consolas)

```
\definefontfamily[f][mono][Latin Modern Mono][rscale=0.8,features=none]
\setupbodyfont[f]
\starttext

\starttyping
-- in lua you can use both single and double quotes
a = 'single quoted'
b = "double quoted"
\stoptyping

\stoptext
```

[image]